# Witcher 3 Hearts of Stone [Add-On] in combination with NG+ [Official DLC]

Tags: the-witcher-3

Today the Witcher 3 Add-On released.

There are three ways of how you can access the story's begin:

**1. Start from beginning:**

- No Savegame required.
- Starting with the first quest to *Hearts of Stone* immeditely after Prolog of the main game.
- Recommended level is 30.

**2. Starting from current save game:**

- If you are midway through the main game, after installation of *Hearts of Stone* you also receive an entry in your quest log like above if you load this save game.

**3. Only Add-On:**

- You are even able to only play the Add-On.
- Starting with a preconfigured Character on Level 32

***Now my Question:*** The first and second way would mean, that you complete the main game (or get until around level30) and then start with the Add-On, but what if you have completed the main game and started a `New Game +`? Can I instantly begin with *Hearts of Stone* or is the difficulty raised, so that I have to play parts of the main game again, too?

This is my case since I uninstalled *Witcher 3* and only have a savegame with very high gere and in the begin of `New Game +` left.

Furthermore the second way is no compromise as nearly every RPGer would understand since you did not achieve anything by yourself ;-)

Comment: I currently don't have the Add-On otherwise I would've just tested it of course :-) Thus the post can lead to a purchase decision depending on your answers. Maybe someone could just test it, who purchased it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantly begin, as long as you are done with the Prologue. The difficulty will either scale with your level 30 character, or your level of difficulty in NG+.

In your case, after you are done with the Prologue, you'll start the game with a quest in your journal and the enemies will be associated with your difficulty level at the time the journal entry was created.

Comment: Beat me to it - nice one. That makes me feel much better about having started (but not done too much) on my NG+.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, NG+ is mostly an opportunity to make different choices and have completely different outcomes. They didn't really force you into playing any particular way the second time, which I think is a really nice touch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I wanted and in the weekend I am gonna start to play I assume :-)